# Powershell: Create named range for non-contiguous cells in excel

Tags: powershell

```
$file="mytestfile.xlsx"
$tab="metric"
$excel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$wb=$excel.WorkBooks.Open("$pwd\$file")
$ws = $wb.sheets.item("$tab")
$cells = @("$tab!K19","$tab!K39","$tab!K58","$tab!K78")
$name = "$tab!myRange"
$wb.names.add($name, $cells)
$wb.save()
$excel.quit()
```

Then i can see a ranage named Metric!MyRange={"metric!K19","metric!K39","metric!K58","metric!K78"} was created in the name manager. But if i refer to it an error popped up said location or data range is invalid.
I think the problem is the additonal {} and "" - i think the correct format should be Metric!MyRange,metric!K19,metric!K39,metric!K58,metric!K78 - but I have no idea how to, as this is from a string array. I have no way to remove the "". Even i did a join to turn the array into a string there will be leading and trailing ""
Appreciate your input

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer!
The trick is:

```
       $refTo = $cells -join ","    
       $refTo = "=${refTo}"
```

and then

```
   $rangename = "${tab}!${key}"
   $wb.names.add($rangename,$refTo ) | out-null
```